# Unable to modify variables of a class in c++

Tags: c++, class, variables

I'm trying to update variable `dist` in the `Vertex` class. The `Vertex` object is kept in the value of the `unordered_map` of the `Graph` class (`vertices`) .
The problem I'm having is that when I try to modify the dist variable via `g.get_vertex(vert).set_distance(34)`     (here `g` is graph object and `vert` is a vertex name  whose value pair in `unordered_map` holds its vertex object)  it fails to make any changes. e.g
if I do

```
g.get_vertex(vert).set_distance(34);
cout << g.get_vertex(vert).get_distance()
```

gives 10000000 instead of 34 (10000000  was defined as  dist value in the default constructor).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Vertex{    
public:
    int  dist ;
    unordered_map <int,int> connected_to ;

    Vertex(){
        connected_to;
        dist=10000000;
    }

    void add_neighbour(int x, int y){
        connected_to[x] = y;
    }
    void set_distance(int d){
        dist = d;
    }
    int get_neighbour(int x){
        return connected_to[x];
    }
    int get_distance(){
        return dist;
    }
    unordered_map <int,int> get_connections(){
        return  connected_to;
    }    
};

class Graph{    
    unordered_map <int , Vertex > vertices;  int vert_num;
public:    
    Graph(){
        vertices;
        vert_num=0;
    }
    void add_vertex(int x){
        Vertex New_vert;
        vertices[x] = New_vert;
        vert_num+=1;
    }
    void add_edge(int x, int y , int dist){
        if (vertices.find(x) == vertices.end() ){
            add_vertex(x);
        }
        if ( vertices.find(y) == vertices.end() ){
            add_vertex(y);
        }
        Vertex vert ;
        vert.add_neighbour(y, dist);
        Vertex vert2 ;
        vert2.add_neighbour(x, dist);
    }
    Vertex get_vertex(int x){
        return vertices[x];
    }
    unordered_map<int , Vertex> get_vertices(){
        return vertices;
    }
    int get_num(){
        return vert_num;
    }
};
```

Comment: Your constructor bodies aren't exactly wrong, but the useless expressions suggest you have a very wrong concept of the syntax for initializing class members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_vertex` returns by value, so you're effectively modifying a copy of the element in `vertices`. Return by reference to get the behavior you're expecting

```
Vertex& getVertex(int x)
```

simiar for `get_vertices()` and `get_connections()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with this code. An incomplete list is as follows.

1. `int vert_num` is unnecessary, simply use `std::unordered_map<>::size()`
2. the constructors are not required (will be default generated)
3. you're often modifying temporary objects, for example in

   ```
   void add_edge(int x, int y , int dist){
       if (vertices.find(x) == vertices.end() ){
           add_vertex(x);
       }
       if (vertices.find(y) == vertices.end() ){
           add_vertex(y);
       }
       Vertex vert ;                    // automatic/temporary object
       vert.add_neighbour(y, dist);     // modify the object
       Vertex vert2 ;                   
       vert2.add_neighbour(x, dist);
                                        // end of scope: temporaries are destroyed
   }
   ```

   the code in the last 4 lines does nothing (and may be optimized away). What you presumably meant to do was

   ```
   void add_edge(int x, int y , int dist){
       vertices[x].add_neighbour(y, dist);
       vertices[y].add_neighbour(x, dist);
   }
   ```

   (note that `unordered_map<>::operator[]` inserts a new element if non is found for the key given).
4. You return copies in

   ```
   Vertex get_vertex(int x){
       return vertices[x];
   }
   unordered_map<int,Vertex> get_vertices(){
       return vertices;
   }
   ```

   the modification of which in code like

   ```
   g.get_vertex(vert).set_distance(34);
   ```

   has no effect on the actual `Vertex` stored in `Graph`. Instead you should

   ```
   Vertex&get_vertex(int x){
       return vertices[x];
   }
   Vertex const&get_vertex(int x) const {
       auto find=vertices.find(x);
       if(find==vertices.end())
           throw std::runtime_error("unknown vertex requested");
       return find->second;
   }
   unordered_map<int,Vertex>&get_vertices(){
       return vertices;
   }
   unordered_map<int,Vertex> const&get_vertices() const{
       return vertices;
   }
   ```

   though arguably you should not expose the `vertices` map (any functionality that would require that should be dealt with by `class Graph`).

Answer (score 0):

This function returns a new `Vertex` instance copied from the collection

```
Vertex get_vertex(int x)
{
    return vertices[x];
}
```

Those changes are lost when the temporary object dies.